# Angular dependency injection does not recognise module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble properly injecting a bunch of modules in a project. This is the project I’m following

https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial

When i try to make a new post - angular throws the below error

```
Error: Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount(...) is undefined
submit@http://localhost:8000/static/javascripts/posts/controllers/new-post.controller.js:31:21
$parseFunctionCall@http://localhost:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12474:15
```

This is where the problem seems to occur

```
function NewPostController($rootScope, $scope, Authentication, Snackbar, Posts) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.submit = submit;

    function submit() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('post.created', {
        content: vm.content,
        author: {
          username: Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount().username
        }
      });

      $scope.closeThisDialog();

      Posts.create(vm.content).then(createPostSuccessFn, createPostErrorFn);

      function createPostSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Snackbar.show('Success! Post created.');
      }

      function createPostErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('post.created.error');
        Snackbar.error(data.error);
      }
    }
  }
```

But I can see that the correct module is being used in the code.

this is my new-post.controller.js file where i've injected the Authentication dependency

```
  angular
    .module('thinkster.posts.controllers')
    .controller('NewPostController', NewPostController);

  NewPostController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Authentication', 'Snackbar', 'Posts'];
```

this is a snippet my posts.module.js file

```
  angular
    .module('thinkster.posts', [
      'thinkster.posts.controllers',
      'thinkster.posts.directives',
      'thinkster.posts.services'
    ]);


 angular
    .module('thinkster.posts.controllers', []);
```

this is a snippet of the authentication service module

```
  angular
    .module('thinkster.authentication.services')
    .factory('Authentication',Authentication);

  Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies','$http'];

  function Authentication($cookies,$http){
    var Authentication = {
      getAuthenticatedAccount: getAuthenticatedAccount,
      isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
      register:register,
      login : login,
      logout:logout,
      setAuthenticatedAccount: setAuthenticatedAccount,
      unAuthenticate: unAuthenticate
    };

    return Authentication;

    function getAuthenticatedAccount(){
      if (!$cookies.authenticatedAccount){
        return;
      }
      return JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount);
    }
```

And a snippet of the authentication module

```
  angular
    .module('thinkster.authentication',[
      'thinkster.authentication.controllers',
      'thinkster.authentication.services'
    ]);
```

-finally, the below thinkster module

```
angular
  .module('thinkster', [
    'thinkster.config',
    'thinkster.routes',
    'thinkster.authentication',
    'thinkster.layout',
    'thinkster.posts',
    'thinkster.utils'
  ]);
```

the authentication service works fine since I’m able to login and logout of the project. Am i looking in the wrong place for the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippets are missing the NewPostController definition. Without seeing that code, I would guess that the Authentication object may not be passed into the function.

```
function NewPostController($rootScope, $scope, Authentication, Snackbar, Posts) {
}
```

You can see what methods are available on your Authentication object with the following code in NewPostController:

```
for (var key in Authentication) {
    console.log(typeof Authentication[key], key);
}
```

You should see "function getAuthenticatedAccount" if it's available on the object.

Comment: updated with full code of NewPostController - the Authentication object is passed to the function

Comment: I've added code in the answer above that can be used for seeing what methods are available on your Authentication object.

Comment: Yea - looks like the function is available in the object. but the error still exists :/ wierd

Comment: Looks like $cookies.authenticatedAccount is undefined . that could be where the problem is